# Add a clickeable icon in title bar

Tags: android, android-titlebar

**I want to add a clickable icon on the default title bar looks like**

**edited with**

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.add("title is needed");
    menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.call);
    return true;
}
```

[image]

**Looks like**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override method onCreateOptionsMenu in your activity:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.add("title if needed");
        menuItem.setIcon(R.drawable.YOUR_ICON_HERE);
        // the rest of the code here...
    }
```

In fact if you are planning to use this action bar on old platforms as well (2.x-3.x), you better consider using ActionBarSherlock

Comment: Multiple markers at this line
 - This method must return a result of type 
  boolean
 - overrides 
  android.app.Activity.onCreateOptionsMenu

Comment: * @return You must return true for the menu to be displayed;
     *         if you return false it will not be shown.

Comment: This might help: menuItem.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);

Comment: Call requires API level 11 (current min is 7): android.view.MenuItem#setShowAsAction

**I need to support from API 7**

Comment: If you want to use Action Bar and icons explicitly in API 7 you have to use AcitonBarSherlock.

Comment: Any other solution like if API level bellow 11 the show default (No icon) other wise it will show icon

Answer (score 0):

Check this code,

```
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Used to put dark icons on light action bar

    menu.add("Search")
    .setOnMenuItemClickListener(new OnMenuItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Intent search = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SearchActivity.class);

            startActivityForResult(search, 0);
            overridePendingTransition( R.anim.righttoleft, R.anim.stable );

            return false;
        }
    }).setIcon(R.drawable.ic_search)
    .setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_ALWAYS);






    return true;
}
```

Comment: Should I add **@Override** before this method

Comment: @bumba: I thnk no need for that